# Can't read/write external HDD created in Windows 7 (NTFS)

Tags: mount, hard-disk, ntfs

I need to have access to my external HHD created in Windows 7.

I installed `ntfs-3g`, now I can see it mounted but I don't have access to it.

There's an error:

`Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/yezhik/F6340FE9340FABA5: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper progarm, or other error`

Comment: Install the missing packages https://askubuntu.com/questions/772179/ntfs-filesystem-on-external-drive-isnt-recognised-mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-o

Comment: @BlockchainOffice I installed the`ntfs-3g`package. Restarted my notebook and tried to enter the HDD. I've got a message about problems with mounting and I tried `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt` and the reply was `Failed to write lock '/dev/sdb1': Resource temporarily unavailable
Error opening '/dev/sdb1': Resource temporarily unavailable
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: don't use ntfs-3g. Since kernel v5.15 Linux already supported NTFS natively with the much better kernel driver